# Silverlight & Visual Tree Manipulation

Tags: silverlight, dom-manipulation, visual-tree

Now this **may** be more trouble than it's worth but nevertheless, it'd be really useful to me right now.

What I'd like to know is how I might go about manipulating the Silverlight visual tree at runtime.  Doing simple things like adding and removing controls is easy enough but when you start having to traverse the tree with any reasonable amount of complexity I find myself yearning for a JQuery style syntax (LINQ would be pretty cool too I suppose) to handle DOM node replacements, movements and the like.

So I guess the question is are there any libraries out there to make this an easier job or is there something baked in that I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Linq extension methods are what you are after but you need to put inplace a litte infrastructure first:-

```
public static class VisualTreeEnumeration
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root, int depth)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
            yield return child;
            if (depth > 0)
            {
                foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child, --depth))
                    yield return descendent;
            }
        }
     }

     public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root)
     {
          return Descendents(root, Int32.MaxValue); 
     }

     public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Ancestors(this DependencyObject root)
     {
          DependencyObject current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
          while (current != null)
          {
              yield return current;
              current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
          }
     }
 }
```

Now you can use Linq to query into the visual tree using Linq.  Some examples:-

```
 // Get all text boxes in usercontrol:-
 this.Descendents().OfType<TextBox>();

 // All UIElement direct children of the layout root grid:-
 LayoutRoot.Descendents(0).OfType<UIElement>();

 // Find the containing `ListBoxItem` for an element:-
 elem.Ancestors().OfType<ListBoxItem>.FirstOrDefault();

 // Seek button with name "PinkElephants" even if outside of the current Namescope:-
 this.Descendents()
    .OfType<Button>()
    .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "PinkElephants");
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this [LINQ to Visual Tree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

what version of silverlight is this?
And what year of " Dec 13 at 13:13" is this post from?

in the current version of SL4 it does not seem to be there..

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get controls from the visual tree

```
    public static FrameworkElement GetComponent(object child, Type t, Type bailOn)
    {
        if (child == null) return null;

        DependencyObject control = (DependencyObject)child; // VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((DependencyObject)x);

        while (control != null)
        {
            if (!control.Equals(child))
            {
                if (control.GetType() == t)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (control is FrameworkElement)
            {
                control = (control as FrameworkElement).Parent;
            }
            else if ((control is DataGridBoundColumn)) // data grid  fucken columns
            {
                control = GetDataGridBoundColumnDataGrid(control);

            }
            if (control != null && bailOn != null && bailOn.GetType() == control.GetType())
            {
                return null;
            }

        }

        // try VTH as we did not find it, as that works some times and the above does not
        if (control == null)
        {
            control = (DependencyObject)child; // start again

            while (control != null)
            {
                if (!control.Equals(child))
                {
                    if (control.GetType() == t)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (control is FrameworkElement)
                {
                    control = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((control as FrameworkElement));
                }
                else if (control is DataGridBoundColumn)
                {
                    control = GetDataGridBoundColumnDataGrid(control);
                }

                if (control != null && bailOn != null && bailOn.GetType() == control.GetType())
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }

        }
        return control as FrameworkElement;
    }

    public static List<FrameworkElement> GetComponentsByType(FrameworkElement parent, Type type)
    {
        List<FrameworkElement> controls = new List<FrameworkElement>();
        GetComponentsByTypeWorker(parent, type, controls);
        return controls;

    }
    private static void GetComponentsByTypeWorker(FrameworkElement parent, Type type, List<FrameworkElement> controls)
    {

        if (parent.GetType() == type)
        {
            controls.Add(parent as FrameworkElement);
        }

        int cnt = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as FrameworkElement;
            if (child.GetType() == type)
            {
                controls.Add(child as FrameworkElement);
            }

            int cnt2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(child);
            for (int j = 0; j < cnt2; j++)
            {
                FrameworkElement child2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(child, j) as FrameworkElement;

                GetComponentsByTypeWorker(child2 as FrameworkElement, type, controls);
            }
        }




    }
```